# img losing id when changing src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a webpage where you can oreder a ticket to a cinema movie.I have used an algorithm to change the cinema ticked price based on spot's id. The problem is that when I change the src of the image I get an undefined id. Why do I get that, and how to fix it?. Here is the code:

```
window.onload = main;
var initialPrice = 0;
var dayMultiplier = 1;
var price = 0;
function main()
{
    addButtonLsn();
}

function addButtonLsn()
{
    $("#setDate").click(addSeats);  
}

function addSeats()
{
    if($("#zi").val() === "--*--")
    {
        alert("Day select missing");
        return; 
    }

    if($("#movies").val() ==="--*--")
    {
        alert("Movie select missing");
        return; 
    }
    setInitialPrice();
    setDayMutliplier();
    $("#sala").empty();
    $("#price").html("Pret : 0");
    var myId = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            var s = document.createElement("img");  
            s.setAttribute("src", "liber.jpg");
            s.setAttribute("id", myId);
            myId ++;
            s.addEventListener("click", changeSeat);
            s.addEventListener("mouseover", getSeatTicket);
            var d = document.getElementById("sala");
            d.appendChild(s);
        }   
    }
}

function getSeatTicket()
{
    var spotPrice = initialPrice;
    spotPrice = initialPrice * dayMultiplier;
    var spotMultiplyer = 1;
    var ct = 1;
    if($(this).attr("id") < 130)
    {
        spotMultiplyer = 1;
        ct = 3;
    }
    else if ($(this).attr("id") < 180)
    {
        spotMultiplyer = 1.1;
        ct = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        spotMultiplyer = 1.2;
        ct = 1;
    }

    spotPrice *= spotMultiplyer;
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));//undefined
    $(this).attr("title","Categorie: " + ct + " ,pret " + spotPrice);
    return spotPrice;
}

function changeSeat()
{
    if($(this).attr('src') === "liber.jpg")
    {
        $(this).attr('src','rezervat.jpg');
        price = price + getSeatTicket();
        $("#price").html("Price: " + price);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr('src','liber.jpg');
        price = price - getSeatTicket();
        $("#price").html("Price: " + price);
    }
}

function setInitialPrice()
{
    if($("#movies").val() === "The Gold Rush")
    {
        initialPrice = 10;
        return; 
    }   
    if($("#movies").val() === "The Kid")
    {
        initialPrice = 11;  
        return;
    }   

    if($("#movies").val() === "Modern Times")
    {
        initialPrice = 12;
        return; 
    }   
}

function setDayMutliplier()
{
    if($("#zi").val() === "Luni-Joi")
    {
        dayMultiplier = 1;
        return; 
    }
    if($("#zi").val() === "Vineri")
    {
        dayMultiplier = 1.1;    
        return; 
    }
    if($("#zi").val() === "Sambata")
    {
        dayMultiplier = 1.2;    
        return; 
    }
    if($("#zi").val() === "Duminica")
    {
        dayMultiplier = 1.3;
        return;     
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you incrementing myid inside the for loop after having incremented my id inline with the for keyword?

Comment: I am incrementing myId only in the for for loop.

Comment: Where in the code are you getting undefined id? `function changeSeat()`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles console.log();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getSeatTicket` is referring to `this` as the current element, which works fine when the function is used as a callback for the mouseover listener, but it will not work when you are calling it as you are in `changeSeat`.

Perhaps you should be using `.call(this)` to run the function using the same scope as `changeSeat`;

```
function changeSeat()
{
    if($(this).attr('src') === "liber.jpg")
    {
        $(this).attr('src','rezervat.jpg');
        price = price + getSeatTicket.call(this);
        $("#price").html("Price: " + price);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr('src','liber.jpg');
        price = price - getSeatTicket.call(this);
        $("#price").html("Price: " + price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After code inspection, my guess is that when you try to access the element's id within the getSeatTicket() function, you are calling a function where $(this) is not actually refering to  the DOM element to which the event is attached to.

To overcome this, my recommendation would be to pass the id to the getSeatTicket() function, and getting the reference to the element inside it. Something like (conceptual):

```
function getSeatTicket(id){
    var element = $(id);

    ...
}
```

and call it like:

```
...

 $(this).attr('src','rezervat.jpg');
 price = price + getSeatTicket($(this).attr("id"));
...
```

Best.

Comment: The `getSeatTicket` function is also used as the callback for the `mouseover` event, and that would no longer work if you use an argument to get the ID.